# How create custom map on Power BI using Image?

Tags: business-intelligence, powerbi

I am planning to create a custom map visualization using an Image as a map. I already did this on Spotfire but now we are switching to Power BI. How to use image as a map in POWER BI? I have data which have coordinates.

I need to create a dashboard like on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3Mwd3fZm3o.

Thanks in advance.

FYI: I am using this version: 2.43.4647.541 64-bit (February, 2017)

Aze

Comment: Your question seems a bit broad; [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals) should help you getting started with PowerBI custom visual development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a look at the Synoptic Panel custom visual by OkViz: http://okviz.com/synoptic-panel/

It allows you to upload an image and then plot data points (or areas) on it. There's an introduction here (but it's more than a year old, so expect some things to have changed). https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/visual-awesomeness-unlocked-using-the-synoptic-panel/

The dashboard in the video was created using a different tool: Power Map in Excel (called 3D Map in Excel 2016). This also allowed you to substitute a custom image. However, 3D Map is not part of all versions of Excel, and isn't yet incorporated into the tool now called Power BI, which is why I'd recommend looking at Synoptic Panel for your stated needs (data with coordinates on a custom image).

*Disclaimer: I didn't create the linked video, and I'm not part of OkViz*